# npm ERR! gyp Linux Mint 21.3 virginia (x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Tags: linux, gulp, npm, gcc, linux-mint

При установке gulp, gulp-responsive получаю ошибки:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/oem/Projects/NextLevel-gulp/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/oem/Projects/NextLevel-gulp/node_modules/sharp/build'
npm ERR!   TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/oem/Projects/NextLevel-gulp/node_modules/sharp/build'
npm ERR! info sharp Detected globally-installed libvips v8.12.1
npm ERR! info sharp Building from source via node-gyp
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.12 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
```

На node15 все работает, но на node 18 - 20 получаю ошибки выше.
Пробовал:

1. Переустановка node
2. ОБновление Phython
3. Установка глобальной переменной PATH в .profile
4. ОБновление node-gyp
5. Поиск подобных issue на github sharp, gulp-responsive, node-gyp
6. Смотрел GCC, но не понял как правильно обновить

Доп информация о системе:

```
oem@pc1:~/Projects/NextLevel-gulp$ node-gyp -v
v10.0.1
oem@pc1:~/Projects/NextLevel-gulp$ node -v
v20.11.1
oem@pc1:~/Projects/NextLevel-gulp$ python --version
Python 3.10.12
oem@pc1:~/Projects/NextLevel-gulp$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
```

Если есть решение или доп инфа - буду благодарен. Я бы и дальше использовал node 15, но в проект добавился gulp плагин, который требует node не ниже 18 версии.

Поочередное использование разных версий node как крайнюю меру